# Jekyll execute bash script every time after regenerate with --watch option

Tags: ruby, jekyll, jekyll-extensions

I'm using `jekyll build --watch` to automatically regenerate _site folder when I make changes.

I also have a script that resolve CDN url in the _site directory. But I have to run that script manually every time Jekyll regenerate the content.

How can I set option on Jekyll to execute my CDN resolve bash script automatically after regenerate _site folder ?

Comment: You can use a Jekyll hook plugin : https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/#hooks

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest adding Gulp to your Jekyll workflow, to accomplish this... a simple google search for `jekyll gulp` will lead you down to many tutorials on how to achieve this.